# React - using arrows in a button

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use arrows in buttons and I'm using the entities as described [here](http://cactus.io/resources/toolbox/html-arrow-symbol-codes)

If I use one of these entities values (like: & larr;) hardcoded then the change is reflected, but in my case this value is coming within an api call and I'm building it dynamiclly.

when using the value coming from api, the text (aka: & larr;) is displayed instead.

```
<Button key={element.Id}
         onClick={() => this.onInputChange(element.Id)}>
      {/*{element.Value}*/} &larr;
</Button>
```

How to deal with it in such case? Tried using javascript eval but didn't help.

Comment: Button is from materialUI?

Comment: i don't understand your approche. usually we use button with icon 

https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

Comment: it's antD in my case. Usually you are right, but in this case I'm working with api and I didn't want to do extra effort for converting what he sends me back as json to icons.. it should work, if I use it hardcoded then it looks very fine... so why when using {value} its not!

Comment: because it's not interpreted the same way, one "hard codded" and one with { }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display an HTML entity within dynamic content, you will run into double escaping issues as React escapes all the strings you are displaying in order to prevent a wide range of XSS attacks by default.  A safer alternative is to find the unicode number corresponding to the entity and use it inside of a JavaScript string.

```
{String.fromCharCode(8592)}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Very simple

Answer (score 1):

first install materialui

```
    npm install @material-ui/core
```

then try something link this

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ArrowBackIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack';

<Button
    key={element.Id}
    variant="contained"
    color="default"         
    startIcon={<ArrowBackIcon />}
     onClick={() => this.onInputChange(element.Id)}
  >
    {element.Value}
  </Button>
```

You can search icon here

https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/

Comment: I'll adopt the icon approch, but not in this way. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "&larr;" }}` like:

```js
<Button
    key={element.Id}
    onClick={() => this.onInputChange(element.Id)}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "&larr;" }}
>
   {element.Value}
</Button>
```

Comment: mmm now I get it. I avoided using this property because of security concerns (besides, it can be used only once and I have many buttons). But now it's clear to me why. I think that I'll switch to icons - seems no other way

Comment: @M_Z better yet use SVGs. Here's how I'd do it using https://heroicons.dev/ -> https://tailwindcss.com/course/working-with-svg-icons/